# What's the purpose to set resume=uuid=xxxxx in grub boot parameter?

Tags: grub2

I see some machines set `resume=uuid=xxxxx` in grub boot parameter.

I think when setting `boot=uuid=xxx` means to specify the boot disk.

How about set `resume=uuid=xxx` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where the hibernation status is saved and from where it should be loaded. Usually this should point to your swap partition. Notably booting to a fresh session and resuming from hibernation have some differences, like e.g. hibernation saving the desktop session with all windows etc.